# History api не меняет title

Tags: history-api, html5-history-api, javascript

Почему `history.pushState({foo: 'bar'}, 'Title', 'url')` не меняет Title на странице.
Вот [сайт](http://new.interrol.by/)

Строчка 177 в `events.js`, `r` прилетает в консоль.

Comment: title — Firefox currently ignores this parameter, although it may use it in the future. Passing the empty string here should be safe against future changes to the method. Alternatively, you could pass a short title for the state to which you're moving.

Comment: Кстати, это так задумано, чтобы при нажатии назад оно полчаса грузилось? Может, стоит кэшировать полученые ответы? Ну еще заодно понажимайте вперед-назад быстро, думаю, нужно выбрасывать рендеринг страницы, если запрошена другая.

Comment: А как их кэшировать? В историю пихать то, что приходит в 'r', или есть способ попроще?